# Access TabBarController variables in sub-ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Basically, I have a TabBarController and some sub-views attached to this controller. The TabBarController has some properties that I would like to access in the sub-views.

Here's what I have :

MyTabBarController's .m

```
-(void)setDetails:(id)sender
{
    self.myVariable = @"This is a test";
    NSLog(@"Here I set my variable");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"[LOAD] My Tab Bar Controller");
    [self setDetails:nil];
}
```

First subView's .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"[LOAD] FirstViewController");

    MyTabBarController *myTBC = (MyTabBarController *)self.tabBarController;
    self.headerName.text = myTBC.myViariable; // Here I just set the UILabel's text
    NSLog(@"Header name = %@", self.headerName);
}
```

Here's what I have in the logs :

```
2012-08-07 11:43:23.001 MyFirstproject[23632:15203] [LOAD] My Tab Bar Controller
2012-08-07 11:43:23.012 MyFirstproject[23632:15203] [LOAD] FirstViewController
2012-08-07 11:43:23.072 MyFirstproject[23751:15203] Header name = (null)
2012-08-07 11:43:23.116 MyFirstproject[23751:15203] Here I set my variable
```

My question is : As I can see in the logs, the `viewDidLoad` function of MyTabBarController is called **before** the FirstViewController's one. However, it seems the function `setDetails` of MyTabBarController is called **after** the function `viewDidLoad` of the FirstViewController.

How can this be possible ? Is there something I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try to put the code for firstViewController in `viewDidAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad` :)

Comment: It worked, thanks. What are the differences between those two functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the code for `firstViewController` in `viewDidAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad`

Happy Coding :)

And for the difference bet'n those two just check it out the documentation regarding it on Apple's developer site :)

Formally `viewDidLoad` call's once at the time of loading the view

And `viewDidAppear`call's when ever the view is about to appeared on the screen :)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: You are well comed :) and can ask for help any time :)